# cannot transition between view controller when clicking a table cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to transition from one view controller into another when clicking a table cell without any additional data passing. Here is a screenshot of my storyboard: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZX3mO.jpg

However, it doesn't go to the second view controller when I am clicking on the table cell. They are both embedded in the navigation controller (I think; since the "Navigation Item" is in both controllers). What am I missing?

Comment: The issue was so bizarre that even without any code snippet (using UIViewController as the default controller) the segue didn't work... Therefore, I just recreated the project thinking something went wrong in the Delegate or something. And after recreating it, everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have mapped your table data source and table delegate to self.

Comment: They are mapped. The problem is really bizarre. I even created a new View Controller, added a button and a segue and it still didn't work...

Comment: http://imgur.com/HlwGLJf - Here. Segues used the same way but instead of table cell its now a button

Answer (score 0):

For that you could use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in that you could programmatically call that other view Controller.

Like below:-

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

  ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];

  [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

This will help you out.

Comment: I wanted to use Segues for Transition. Isn't that possible? That I want to have space for passing data in the future

Comment: You could use segues for connecting tableview with another view or view's and not table view cell with view or view's. ALso you could provide unique identifier to each segues for passing particular data to respective view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that 'user interaction' for both 'table view' and 'table view cell' should be enabled.

[image]

Comment: Can you send the code snippet so that we can identify the issue.